# How do I make chess pieces move (array)?

Tags: vba

I'm working on a chess game as my school project. I'm a beginner, so I thought I would challenge myself, but I underestimated the difficulty. So far I have made the board, and now I'm trying to make the knight. This is what I made so far (springer = knight (ignore the danish notes)):

```
Public Class Form1

Dim x_board(7) As Integer
Dim y_board(7) As Integer


'Prøver at lave boardarrayet
Private board(7, 7) As String

'Den her vil jeg bruge til at lave brikkerne til en form for kategori
Dim brik(17) As String



'Springer koordinater og position
Dim x_springer As Integer = 90
Dim y_springer As Integer = 0



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    Dim name As Integer

    'Lave boardet med to forloops

    For j = 0 To 7
        For i = 0 To 7



            'Definerer boardet
            Dim btn As New PictureBox



            name += 1 'Tæller en op. Den her bruger jeg til at navngive knapperne

            btn.Height = 90
            btn.Width = 90
            btn.Name = name
            btn.Visible = True



            btn.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(i * 90, j * 90)

            'Definere boardet
            If i = 0 And j = 0 Then
                board(0, 0) = "springer"

            End If

            'Definere boardet 
            If i = 1 And j = 0 Then
                board(1, 0) = 1

            End If

            'Definere boardet 
            If i = 2 And j = 0 Then
                board(2, 0) = 2

            End If

            'Definere boardet 
            If i = 3 And j = 0 Then
                board(3, 0) = 3

            End If

            'Definere boardet 
            If i = 4 And j = 0 Then
                board(4, 0) = 4

            End If






            'Jeg dividere det vandrette+lodrette nummer med 2. På den her måde ved jeg, at hvis jeg får 1 tilbage, så er det et ullige nummer. (Til rapporten: Først tog jeg tallets, og det lavede rækkerne hvid-sort-hvid-sort osv.)
            If (i + j) Mod 2 = 1 Then

                btn.BackColor = Color.White
            Else
                btn.BackColor = Color.Black
            End If



            ' Tilføj knapperne så de kan ses
            Me.Controls.Add(btn)




            ' Me.Controls.Add(board(7, 7))

            'Definerer springerbrikken 
            Dim springer As New PictureBox


            springer.Height = 90
            springer.Width = 90
            springer.Visible = True
            springer.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            springer.Enabled = True

            'Tilføj springeren
            Me.Controls.Add(springer)





            'Giver springer en position
            springer.Location = New  System.Drawing.Point(x_springer,y_springer)



            'Jeg laver en addhandler for click-eventet som kommer senere
            AddHandler springer.Click, AddressOf springer_click

        Next
    Next


End Sub

 'Springerens click-event
    Private Sub springer_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


End Class
```

My teacher told me to make the board(7,7) a string. But my knight is a picturebox, and cannot be stored in a string. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an ID to each of your piece. Like saying that 17 is bound to the knight and 18 to the king.
If it is certified that the ID of the piece cant exceed 100, you also can add or don't add 100 to specify the team of the piece.

Comment: How can I bind 17 to a picturebox?

Comment: create a pictureBox array and accede it with the id of the case

Comment: But whenever I try to assign a number to a picturebox, it says that an integer cannot be converted to picturebox. Can you specify?